# Why does jQuery $('#selector').width(1) apply 17px instead of 1px?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code:

```
<select id="mySelect">...</select>
<div style="width:514">
<select id="myOtherSelect" style="100px">...</select>
</div>

$('#myForm').on('change', '#mySelect', function () {
    console.log($('#myOtherSelect').parent().width()); /**Output 514**/
    $('#myOtherSelect').width($('#myOtherSelect').parent().width());
});
```

After `'change'` is triggered:

Console Shows: 514

Inspection shows: `<select id="myOtherSelect" style="width:530px">`

In **every** scenario I've tried, even on different pages, when I try to set a new width with jquery's .width() 16 is added to the value specified.

Tried hard coding value:

```
$('#myOtherSelect').width(514);//SAME RESULT! 530px, tried 1, got 17px, tried 4 got 20px
```

Why is this happening? I'm expecting `<select id="myOtherSelect" style="width:514px">` on `'change'` What is my best alternative?

Comment: So, what's supposed to happen and what's the problem? You aren't clear on what supposed to happen vs what is happening. For example, what is the value of `$('#myOtherSelect').parent().width()`? Is it 530px?

Comment: I still have no idea why this is happening, but this is the best alternative I've come up with so far, working as expected:
`$('#myOtherSelect').css('width',$('#myOtherSelect').parent().width());`

Answer (score 0):

How about try this,

```
$('#myForm').on('change', '#mySelect', function () {
    $('#myOtherSelect').width($('#myOtherSelect').parent().width());
});
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this is what I originally tried (the commented part that isn't working. When I console log $('#myOtherSelect').parent().width() I'm getting 514, before $('#myOtherSelect').width($('#myOtherSelect').parent().width()); is triggered #myOtherSelect is 100px, after it's 530px

Answer (score 0):

Have you inspected the box model in the console?  Maybe that'll show where the extra pixels are hiding?  Also, if these elements are taking up the entire viewport, the 16px might include the scrollbar.

In either case [.innerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/innerwidth/) might work better.

Comment: When I console log `$('#myOtherSelect').parent().width()` I'm getting 514, before `$('#myOtherSelect').width($('#myOtherSelect').parent().width());` is triggered `#myOtherSelect` is 100px, after it's 530px

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to get the width of this element:

```
<select id="myOtherSelect" style="width:530px">
```

But your code:

```
console.log($('#myOtherSelect').parent().width());
```

Is not getting that element, it's getting the width of the parent element, so it's getting the width of the `option`, which may be `514` pixels:

```
<option ... > <!-- <<< This is the parent, not the select -->
    ...
    <select id="myOtherSelect" style="width:530px">
    ...
</option>
```

So just drop the `.parent()` part:

```
console.log($('#myOtherSelect').width());
```

---

My other interpretation is you wish to set the `$('#myOtherSelect')` to the width of the parent, but don't understand why it's still 514 pixels other then the 530 pixels it was set to. In that case you are just logging it before you change it's width, just flip them around:

```
$('#myOtherSelect').width($('#myOtherSelect').parent().width());
console.log($('#myOtherSelect').parent().width()); /**Output 530**/
```